# kong-ingress-controller's EXTERNAL_IP is pending

Tags: kubernetes, kong, kong-ingress

I've installed kong-ingress-controller using yaml file on a 3-nodes k8s cluster( bare metal ) (you can see the file at the bottom of question) and every thing is up and runnig:

```
$kubectl get pods --all-namespaces
NAMESPACE     NAME                                        READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
default       bar-deployment-64d5b5b5c4-99p4q             1/1     Running   0          12m
default       foo-deployment-877bf9974-xmpj6              1/1     Running   0          15m
kong          ingress-kong-5cd9db4db9-4cg4q               2/2     Running   0          79m
kube-system   calico-kube-controllers-5f6cfd688c-5njnn    1/1     Running   0          18h
kube-system   calico-node-5k9b6                           1/1     Running   0          18h
kube-system   calico-node-jbb7k                           1/1     Running   0          18h
kube-system   calico-node-mmmts                           1/1     Running   0          18h
kube-system   coredns-74ff55c5b-5q5fn                     1/1     Running   0          23h
kube-system   coredns-74ff55c5b-9bbbk                     1/1     Running   0          23h
kube-system   etcd-kubernetes-master                      1/1     Running   1          23h
kube-system   kube-apiserver-kubernetes-master            1/1     Running   1          23h
kube-system   kube-controller-manager-kubernetes-master   1/1     Running   1          23h
kube-system   kube-proxy-4h7hs                            1/1     Running   0          20h
kube-system   kube-proxy-sd6b2                            1/1     Running   0          20h
kube-system   kube-proxy-v9z8p                            1/1     Running   1          23h
kube-system   kube-scheduler-kubernetes-master            1/1     Running   1          23h
```

**but the problem is here**:

the **`EXTERNAL_IP`** of **`kong-proxy service`** is **pending** so i'm not able to reach to my cluster from the outside

```
$kubectl get services --all-namespaces
NAMESPACE     NAME                      TYPE           CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)                      AGE
default       bar-service               ClusterIP      10.103.49.102   <none>        5000/TCP                     15m
default       foo-service               ClusterIP      10.102.52.89    <none>        5000/TCP                     19m
default       kubernetes                ClusterIP      10.96.0.1       <none>        443/TCP                      23h
kong          kong-proxy                LoadBalancer   10.104.79.161   <pending>     80:31583/TCP,443:30053/TCP   82m
kong          kong-validation-webhook   ClusterIP      10.109.75.104   <none>        443/TCP                      82m
kube-system   kube-dns                  ClusterIP      10.96.0.10      <none>        53/UDP,53/TCP,9153/TCP       23h
```

```
$ kubectl describe service kong-proxy -n kong

Name:                     kong-proxy
Namespace:                kong
Labels:                   <none>
Annotations:              service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-backend-protocol: tcp
                          service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-type: nlb
Selector:                 app=ingress-kong
Type:                     LoadBalancer
IP Families:              <none>
IP:                       10.104.79.161
IPs:                      10.104.79.161
Port:                     proxy  80/TCP
TargetPort:               8000/TCP
NodePort:                 proxy  31583/TCP
Endpoints:                192.168.74.69:8000
Port:                     proxy-ssl  443/TCP
TargetPort:               8443/TCP
NodePort:                 proxy-ssl  30053/TCP
Endpoints:                192.168.74.69:8443
Session Affinity:         None
External Traffic Policy:  Cluster
Events:                   <none>
```

my k8s version is 1.20.1 and
my docker version is 19.3.10 .
If someone could help me to get a solution ,that would be awesome

=============================================

**kong-ingress-controller** yaml file:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Namespace
metadata:
  name: kong
---
apiVersion: apiextensions.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: CustomResourceDefinition
metadata:
  name: kongclusterplugins.configuration.konghq.com
spec:
  additionalPrinterColumns:
  - JSONPath: .plugin
    description: Name of the plugin
    name: Plugin-Type
    type: string
  - JSONPath: .metadata.creationTimestamp
    description: Age
    name: Age
    type: date
  - JSONPath: .disabled
    description: Indicates if the plugin is disabled
    name: Disabled
    priority: 1
    type: boolean
  - JSONPath: .config
    description: Configuration of the plugin
    name: Config
    priority: 1
    type: string
  group: configuration.konghq.com
  names:
    kind: KongClusterPlugin
    plural: kongclusterplugins
    shortNames:
    - kcp
  scope: Cluster
  subresources:
    status: {}
  validation:
    openAPIV3Schema:
      properties:
        config:
          type: object
        configFrom:
          properties:
            secretKeyRef:
              properties:
                key:
                  type: string
                name:
                  type: string
                namespace:
                  type: string
              required:
              - name
              - namespace
              - key
              type: object
          type: object
        disabled:
          type: boolean
        plugin:
          type: string
        protocols:
          items:
            enum:
            - http
            - https
            - grpc
            - grpcs
            - tcp
            - tls
            type: string
          type: array
        run_on:
          enum:
          - first
          - second
          - all
          type: string
      required:
      - plugin
  version: v1
---
apiVersion: apiextensions.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: CustomResourceDefinition
metadata:
  name: kongconsumers.configuration.konghq.com
spec:
  additionalPrinterColumns:
  - JSONPath: .username
    description: Username of a Kong Consumer
    name: Username
    type: string
  - JSONPath: .metadata.creationTimestamp
    description: Age
    name: Age
    type: date
  group: configuration.konghq.com
  names:
    kind: KongConsumer
    plural: kongconsumers
    shortNames:
    - kc
  scope: Namespaced
  subresources:
    status: {}
  validation:
    openAPIV3Schema:
      properties:
        credentials:
          items:
            type: string
          type: array
        custom_id:
          type: string
        username:
          type: string
  version: v1
---
apiVersion: apiextensions.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: CustomResourceDefinition
metadata:
  name: kongingresses.configuration.konghq.com
spec:
  group: configuration.konghq.com
  names:
    kind: KongIngress
    plural: kongingresses
    shortNames:
    - ki
  scope: Namespaced
  subresources:
    status: {}
  validation:
    openAPIV3Schema:
      properties:
        proxy:
          properties:
            connect_timeout:
              minimum: 0
              type: integer
            path:
              pattern: ^/.*$
              type: string
            protocol:
              enum:
              - http
              - https
              - grpc
              - grpcs
              - tcp
              - tls
              type: string
            read_timeout:
              minimum: 0
              type: integer
            retries:
              minimum: 0
              type: integer
            write_timeout:
              minimum: 0
              type: integer
          type: object
        route:
          properties:
            headers:
              additionalProperties:
                items:
                  type: string
                type: array
              type: object
            https_redirect_status_code:
              type: integer
            methods:
              items:
                type: string
              type: array
            path_handling:
              enum:
              - v0
              - v1
              type: string
            preserve_host:
              type: boolean
            protocols:
              items:
                enum:
                - http
                - https
                - grpc
                - grpcs
                - tcp
                - tls
                type: string
              type: array
            regex_priority:
              type: integer
            request_buffering:
              type: boolean
            response_buffering:
              type: boolean
            snis:
              items:
                type: string
              type: array
            strip_path:
              type: boolean
        upstream:
          properties:
            algorithm:
              enum:
              - round-robin
              - consistent-hashing
              - least-connections
              type: string
            hash_fallback:
              type: string
            hash_fallback_header:
              type: string
            hash_on:
              type: string
            hash_on_cookie:
              type: string
            hash_on_cookie_path:
              type: string
            hash_on_header:
              type: string
            healthchecks:
              properties:
                active:
                  properties:
                    concurrency:
                      minimum: 1
                      type: integer
                    healthy:
                      properties:
                        http_statuses:
                          items:
                            type: integer
                          type: array
                        interval:
                          minimum: 0
                          type: integer
                        successes:
                          minimum: 0
                          type: integer
                      type: object
                    http_path:
                      pattern: ^/.*$
                      type: string
                    timeout:
                      minimum: 0
                      type: integer
                    unhealthy:
                      properties:
                        http_failures:
                          minimum: 0
                          type: integer
                        http_statuses:
                          items:
                            type: integer
                          type: array
                        interval:
                          minimum: 0
                          type: integer
                        tcp_failures:
                          minimum: 0
                          type: integer
                        timeout:
                          minimum: 0
                          type: integer
                      type: object
                  type: object
                passive:
                  properties:
                    healthy:
                      properties:
                        http_statuses:
                          items:
                            type: integer
                          type: array
                        interval:
                          minimum: 0
                          type: integer
                        successes:
                          minimum: 0
                          type: integer
                      type: object
                    unhealthy:
                      properties:
                        http_failures:
                          minimum: 0
                          type: integer
                        http_statuses:
                          items:
                            type: integer
                          type: array
                        interval:
                          minimum: 0
                          type: integer
                        tcp_failures:
                          minimum: 0
                          type: integer
                        timeout:
                          minimum: 0
                          type: integer
                      type: object
                  type: object
                threshold:
                  type: integer
              type: object
            host_header:
              type: string
            slots:
              minimum: 10
              type: integer
          type: object
  version: v1
---
apiVersion: apiextensions.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: CustomResourceDefinition
metadata:
  name: kongplugins.configuration.konghq.com
spec:
  additionalPrinterColumns:
  - JSONPath: .plugin
    description: Name of the plugin
    name: Plugin-Type
    type: string
  - JSONPath: .metadata.creationTimestamp
    description: Age
    name: Age
    type: date
  - JSONPath: .disabled
    description: Indicates if the plugin is disabled
    name: Disabled
    priority: 1
    type: boolean
  - JSONPath: .config
    description: Configuration of the plugin
    name: Config
    priority: 1
    type: string
  group: configuration.konghq.com
  names:
    kind: KongPlugin
    plural: kongplugins
    shortNames:
    - kp
  scope: Namespaced
  subresources:
    status: {}
  validation:
    openAPIV3Schema:
      properties:
        config:
          type: object
        configFrom:
          properties:
            secretKeyRef:
              properties:
                key:
                  type: string
                name:
                  type: string
              required:
              - name
              - key
              type: object
          type: object
        disabled:
          type: boolean
        plugin:
          type: string
        protocols:
          items:
            enum:
            - http
            - https
            - grpc
            - grpcs
            - tcp
            - tls
            type: string
          type: array
        run_on:
          enum:
          - first
          - second
          - all
          type: string
      required:
      - plugin
  version: v1
---
apiVersion: apiextensions.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: CustomResourceDefinition
metadata:
  name: tcpingresses.configuration.konghq.com
spec:
  additionalPrinterColumns:
  - JSONPath: .status.loadBalancer.ingress[*].ip
    description: Address of the load balancer
    name: Address
    type: string
  - JSONPath: .metadata.creationTimestamp
    description: Age
    name: Age
    type: date
  group: configuration.konghq.com
  names:
    kind: TCPIngress
    plural: tcpingresses
  scope: Namespaced
  subresources:
    status: {}
  validation:
    openAPIV3Schema:
      properties:
        apiVersion:
          type: string
        kind:
          type: string
        metadata:
          type: object
        spec:
          properties:
            rules:
              items:
                properties:
                  backend:
                    properties:
                      serviceName:
                        type: string
                      servicePort:
                        format: int32
                        type: integer
                    type: object
                  host:
                    type: string
                  port:
                    format: int32
                    type: integer
                type: object
              type: array
            tls:
              items:
                properties:
                  hosts:
                    items:
                      type: string
                    type: array
                  secretName:
                    type: string
                type: object
              type: array
          type: object
        status:
          type: object
  version: v1beta1
status:
  acceptedNames:
    kind: ""
    plural: ""
  conditions: []
  storedVersions: []
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  name: kong-serviceaccount
  namespace: kong
---
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: ClusterRole
metadata:
  name: kong-ingress-clusterrole
rules:
- apiGroups:
  - ""
  resources:
  - endpoints
  - nodes
  - pods
  - secrets
  verbs:
  - list
  - watch
- apiGroups:
  - ""
  resources:
  - nodes
  verbs:
  - get
- apiGroups:
  - ""
  resources:
  - services
  verbs:
  - get
  - list
  - watch
- apiGroups:
  - networking.k8s.io
  - extensions
  - networking.internal.knative.dev
  resources:
  - ingresses
  verbs:
  - get
  - list
  - watch
- apiGroups:
  - ""
  resources:
  - events
  verbs:
  - create
  - patch
- apiGroups:
  - networking.k8s.io
  - extensions
  - networking.internal.knative.dev
  resources:
  - ingresses/status
  verbs:
  - update
- apiGroups:
  - configuration.konghq.com
  resources:
  - tcpingresses/status
  verbs:
  - update
- apiGroups:
  - configuration.konghq.com
  resources:
  - kongplugins
  - kongclusterplugins
  - kongcredentials
  - kongconsumers
  - kongingresses
  - tcpingresses
  verbs:
  - get
  - list
  - watch
- apiGroups:
  - ""
  resources:
  - configmaps
  verbs:
  - create
  - get
  - update
---
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: ClusterRoleBinding
metadata:
  name: kong-ingress-clusterrole-nisa-binding
roleRef:
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: kong-ingress-clusterrole
subjects:
- kind: ServiceAccount
  name: kong-serviceaccount
  namespace: kong
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  annotations:
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-backend-protocol: tcp
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-type: nlb
  name: kong-proxy
  namespace: kong
spec:
  ports:
  - name: proxy
    port: 80
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 8000
  - name: proxy-ssl
    port: 443
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 8443
  selector:
    app: ingress-kong
  type: LoadBalancer
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: kong-validation-webhook
  namespace: kong
spec:
  ports:
  - name: webhook
    port: 443
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 8080
  selector:
    app: ingress-kong
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels:
    app: ingress-kong
  name: ingress-kong
  namespace: kong
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: ingress-kong
  template:
    metadata:
      annotations:
        kuma.io/gateway: enabled
        prometheus.io/port: "8100"
        prometheus.io/scrape: "true"
        traffic.sidecar.istio.io/includeInboundPorts: ""
      labels:
        app: ingress-kong
    spec:
      containers:
      - env:
        - name: KONG_PROXY_LISTEN
          value: 0.0.0.0:8000, 0.0.0.0:8443 ssl http2
        - name: KONG_PORT_MAPS
          value: 80:8000, 443:8443
        - name: KONG_ADMIN_LISTEN
          value: 127.0.0.1:8444 ssl
        - name: KONG_STATUS_LISTEN
          value: 0.0.0.0:8100
        - name: KONG_DATABASE
          value: "off"
        - name: KONG_NGINX_WORKER_PROCESSES
          value: "2"
        - name: KONG_ADMIN_ACCESS_LOG
          value: /dev/stdout
        - name: KONG_ADMIN_ERROR_LOG
          value: /dev/stderr
        - name: KONG_PROXY_ERROR_LOG
          value: /dev/stderr
        image: kong:2.5
        lifecycle:
          preStop:
            exec:
              command:
              - /bin/sh
              - -c
              - kong quit
        livenessProbe:
          failureThreshold: 3
          httpGet:
            path: /status
            port: 8100
            scheme: HTTP
          initialDelaySeconds: 5
          periodSeconds: 10
          successThreshold: 1
          timeoutSeconds: 1
        name: proxy
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8000
          name: proxy
          protocol: TCP
        - containerPort: 8443
          name: proxy-ssl
          protocol: TCP
        - containerPort: 8100
          name: metrics
          protocol: TCP
        readinessProbe:
          failureThreshold: 3
          httpGet:
            path: /status
            port: 8100
            scheme: HTTP
          initialDelaySeconds: 5
          periodSeconds: 10
          successThreshold: 1
          timeoutSeconds: 1
      - env:
        - name: CONTROLLER_KONG_ADMIN_URL
          value: https://127.0.0.1:8444
        - name: CONTROLLER_KONG_ADMIN_TLS_SKIP_VERIFY
          value: "true"
        - name: CONTROLLER_PUBLISH_SERVICE
          value: kong/kong-proxy
        - name: POD_NAME
          valueFrom:
            fieldRef:
              apiVersion: v1
              fieldPath: metadata.name
        - name: POD_NAMESPACE
          valueFrom:
            fieldRef:
              apiVersion: v1
              fieldPath: metadata.namespace
        image: kong/kubernetes-ingress-controller:1.3
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        livenessProbe:
          failureThreshold: 3
          httpGet:
            path: /healthz
            port: 10254
            scheme: HTTP
          initialDelaySeconds: 5
          periodSeconds: 10
          successThreshold: 1
          timeoutSeconds: 1
        name: ingress-controller
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8080
          name: webhook
          protocol: TCP
        readinessProbe:
          failureThreshold: 3
          httpGet:
            path: /healthz
            port: 10254
            scheme: HTTP
          initialDelaySeconds: 5
          periodSeconds: 10
          successThreshold: 1
          timeoutSeconds: 1
      serviceAccountName: kong-serviceaccount
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

the short answer is what @iglen_ said [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69177863/12741668) but I decided to explain the solution.

When using a cloud provider the `LoadBalancer` type for Services will be managed and provisioned by the environment (see [k8s docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/create-external-load-balancer/#external-load-balancer-providers)) automatically, but when creating your own baremetal cluster you will need to add the service which will manage provisioning `IPs` for `LoadBalancer` type Services. One such service is [Metal-LB](https://metallb.universe.tf) which is built for this.

Before installation MetalLB Check the [requirements](https://metallb.universe.tf/#requirements).

before we deploying MetalLB we need to do one step:

> If you’re using kube-proxy in IPVS mode, since Kubernetes v1.14.2 you
> have to enable strict ARP mode.

Note, you don’t need this if you’re using kube-router as service-proxy because it is enabling strict ARP by default.
enter this command:

`$ kubectl edit configmap -n kube-system kube-proxy`

in the opened up page search for **mode**, in my case the mode is equal to empty string so i don't need to change any thing but in the case that mode is set to `ipvs` as it said in the installation guide you need to set below configuration in this file:

```
apiVersion: kubeproxy.config.k8s.io/v1alpha1
kind: KubeProxyConfiguration
mode: "ipvs"
ipvs:
  strictARP: true
```

as the next step you need to run these commands:

```
$ kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/metallb/metallb/v0.10.2/manifests/namespace.yaml
$ kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/metallb/metallb/v0.10.2/manifests/metallb.yaml
$ kubectl create secret generic -n metallb-system memberlist --from-literal=secretkey="$(openssl rand -base64 128)"
```

after running above commands we have this:

```
$ kubectl get all -n metallb-system
NAME                              READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
pod/controller-6b78sff7d9-2rv2f   1/1     Running   0          3m
pod/speaker-7bqev                 1/1     Running   0          3m
pod/speaker-txrg5                 1/1     Running   0          3m
pod/speaker-w7th5                 1/1     Running   0          3m

NAME                     DESIRED   CURRENT   READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   NODE SELECTOR            AGE
daemonset.apps/speaker   3         3         3       3            3           kubernetes.io/os=linux   3m

NAME                         READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE
deployment.apps/controller   1/1     1            1           3m

NAME                                    DESIRED   CURRENT   READY   AGE
replicaset.apps/controller-6b78sff7d9   1         1         1       3m
```

MetalLB needs some `IPv4 addresses` :

```
$ ip a s
1: ens160: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
   [...]
    inet 10.240.1.59/24 brd 10.240.1.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute ens160
       valid_lft 425669sec preferred_lft 421269sec
    [...]
```

the `ens160` is my control-plane network interface and as you see its ip range is `10.240.1.59/24` so i'm going to assign a set of ip address in this network:

```
$ sipcalc 10.240.1.59/24
-[ipv4 : 10.240.1.59/24] - 0

[CIDR]
Host address            - 10.240.1.59
Host address (decimal)  - 183500115
Host address (hex)      - AF0031B
Network address         - 10.240.1.0
Network mask            - 255.255.255.0
Network mask (bits)     - 24
Network mask (hex)      - FFFFF000
Broadcast address       - 10.240.1.255
Cisco wildcard          - 0.0.0.255
Addresses in network    - 256
Network range           - 10.240.1.0 - 10.240.1.255
Usable range            - 10.240.1.1 - 10.240.1.254
```

now i'm going to take **10** ip addresses from the `Usable range` and assign it to MetalLB.
let's create a `configmap` for MetalLB :

```
$ sudo nano metallb-cm.yaml
```

paste the below configuration into metallb-cm.yaml:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  namespace: metallb-system
  name: config
data:
  config: |
    address-pools:
    - name: default
      protocol: layer2
      addresses:
      - 10.240.1.100-10.240.1.110
```

then save the file and run this command:

```
$ kubectl create -f metallb-cm.yaml
```

now let's check our services again:

```
$ kubectl get services --all-namespaces
NAMESPACE     NAME                      TYPE           CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)                      AGE
default       bar-service               ClusterIP      10.103.49.102   <none>        5000/TCP                     15m
default       foo-service               ClusterIP      10.102.52.89    <none>        5000/TCP                     19m
default       kubernetes                ClusterIP      10.96.0.1       <none>        443/TCP                      23h
kong          kong-proxy                LoadBalancer   10.104.79.161   10.240.1.100  80:31583/TCP,443:30053/TCP   82m
kong          kong-validation-webhook   ClusterIP      10.109.75.104   <none>        443/TCP                      82m
kube-system   kube-dns                  ClusterIP      10.96.0.10      <none>        53/UDP,53/TCP,9153/TCP       23h
```

as you can see the service of type `LoadBalancer` has an ip address now.

Answer (score 2):

Had the same issue, after days of looking for a solution, I came across [metallb](https://metallb.universe.tf/), from [nginx ingress](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/deploy/baremetal/) installation on bare metal

> MetalLB provides a network load-balancer implementation for Kubernetes
> clusters that do not run on a supported cloud provider, effectively
> allowing the usage of LoadBalancer Services within any cluster

, from their documentation I got this

> Kubernetes does not offer an implementation of network load balancers (Services of type LoadBalancer) for bare-metal clusters. The implementations of network load balancers that Kubernetes does ship with are all glue code that calls out to various IaaS platforms (GCP, AWS, Azure…). If you’re not running on a supported IaaS platform (GCP, AWS, Azure…), LoadBalancers will remain in the “pending” state indefinitely when created.

I didn't finalize the installation but I hope the explanation above answers your question on pending status on external ip